# openpyxl flip chart with datetime category

Tags: python, openpyxl

i want to flip the chart in openpyxl by X axis (originally X axis is ordered from max to min. i want to order from min to max) but

```
chart.x_axis.scaling.orientation = 'minMax'
```

does not work since my categary is datetime. I cannot change the original data.